# Call sync from kernel driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel

I want to make a call to "sync" from a driver loaded in my 3.4 kernel. I have defined the function: "void sync_filesystems(int wait);" and I call it from the driver.

in fs/sync.c, I have removed "static" from the function "void sync_filesystems(int wait)".

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sync.c?v=3.4#L85

What would be the proper way to do the same, aka. call sync from the kernel space?

The question could be more generic and be "how to do syscall from kernel?" and I found a few links from Google but I'm looking here specifically to work on this filesystem call.

Also, I can have a separate kernel thread that will work specifically on this call.

Comment: Why do you need this? What kind of driver are you coding? It looks like a design mistake...

Comment: This is the kind of not constructive comment. It's a very specific situation and I cannot go back to user-space. The question is not why but how.

Comment: No, `sync` affects *every filesystem*, not only "yours". So you should explain why you need that (on some big computers, `sync` can last minutes!). So you should edit your question to explain "your specific situation"; I'm sure there are other ways to solve your overall issue...

Comment: *"It's a very specific situation"* -- And it also seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  There's also the nasty potential of a recursive loop.  A device driver should not be aware of the upper-level filesystem(s).

Comment: It's on an embedded device in an unusual shutdown procedure. User-space can't be accessed. There is only one mmc on the device that needs to be synced.

Comment: It might be better to detail what the unusual shutdown procedure is and why you can't do this in userspace so we can suggest better solutions. As mentioned before, this sounds like a XY problem as it stands.

Comment: Hi, So how did you eventually do "sync" from kernel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call_usermodehelper enables to call user space from kernel space. Obviously, you need to know what you are doing.